# Изменение размеров изображения (bmp 24bit)

Tags: c, bmp, cs50

При целых коэффициентах n=2,3,4... все нормально увеличивается. При дробных
1.5, 1.7 і т.д. каша, кроме 0.5(уменьшение в 2 раза). Не могу найти где проблема зарыта. Слева каша, справа исходное изображение.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include "bmp.h"

 #define headers 54

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
// ensure proper usage
if (argc != 4)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize n(where n>0 and n<100) infile outfile\n");
    return 1;
}

//remember 
float n = atof(argv[1]);

// remember filenames
char *infile = argv[2];
char *outfile = argv[3];

if (n<=0||n>100)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize n(where n>0 and n<100) infile outfile\n");
    return 1;
}

// open input file 
FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
    return 2;
}

// open output file
FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
if (outptr == NULL)
{
    fclose(inptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
    return 3;
}

// read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

// read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

// ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 || 
    bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
{
    fclose(outptr);
    fclose(inptr);
    fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
    return 4;
}
//remember parameters of original file
int width_before=bi.biWidth;
int height_before=bi.biHeight;
int padding_before =(4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

//set new parameters
bi.biWidth*=n;
bi.biHeight*=n;

int padding_after = 0;
bool need_padding = false;

if(bi.biWidth%4!=0)
{
  need_padding = true;
  //calculate new padding
  padding_after=(4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
}
//set new parameters
bi.biSizeImage = abs(bi.biHeight) * (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) +  padding_after);
bf.bfSize = (bi.biSizeImage + headers);


// write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

// write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

int pos = width_before * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding_before;

if(n>=1) //if  enlarge 
{
// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(height_before); i < biHeight; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < width_before; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            //increasing the number of each pixels in f times
            for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)  fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding_before, SEEK_CUR);

        // write outfile row's padding
        for (int p = 0; p < padding_after; p++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }

        // go to the beginning of the current line to continue copying vertically
        fseek(inptr, headers + pos*i, SEEK_SET); 
    }

    // move to a new line
    fseek(inptr, pos , SEEK_CUR);
}
   }else
  //if shrink
{
   int to_del = width_before/bi.biWidth;// position to not draw
   printf("%i  %i",to_del,width_before);
// iterate over infile's scanlines
for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(height_before); i < biHeight; i++)
{
        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        if(i%to_del!=0)//do not draw each to_del row 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width_before; j++)
            {
                // temporary storage
                RGBTRIPLE triple;

                // read RGB triple from infile
                fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

                if(j%to_del!=0) //don't draw each to_del pixel in row 
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);

            }

            // skip over padding, if any
            fseek(inptr, padding_before, SEEK_CUR);

            // write outfile row's padding
            for (int p = 0; p < padding_after; p++)
            {
                fputc(0x00, outptr);
            }
            // go to the beginning of the current line to continue copying vertically
            fseek(inptr, headers + pos*(i-1), SEEK_SET);
        }


}
}
// close infile
fclose(inptr);

// close outfile
fclose(outptr);

// success
return 0;
}
```

[image: каша если ввести дробь]
[image: исходное изображение ( при целых коэффициентах выглядит также но размер другой. P.S. знаю что кеп))]

Comment: Не могу сказать, где именно проблема в вашем коде, но могу сказать, что в идеале при увеличении изображения следует использовать интерполяцию, а при уменьшении свертку с функцией sinc. И если делать это из файла в файл с минимальным использованием памяти, то код должен получиться очень интересный.

Answer (score 1):

```
//set new parameters
bi.biWidth*=n;
bi.biHeight*=n;
```

На базе данного кода, увеличить изображение в нецелое (х1.5, х1.7) количество раз, без потери геометрической целостности того, что изоображаеться, нельзя.

Выход: округлить результат умножения исходных высоты и ширины на аргумент до целого числа:

```
//set new parameters
bi.biWidth = roundf(bi.biWidth * n);
bi.biHeight = roundf(bi.biHeight * n);
```

В случае деления (аргумент меньше единицы), работать будет только х0.5, по упомянутым причинам.